# How to type ñ on my debian system?

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, dead-keys

Dead keys used to work as they should until months ago but since whatever update of my debian/gnome/whatever I fail to both type ñ and to find a solution. I live in Viña, Chile, so it's not so uncommon that I need this :( Typing <kbd>´</kbd> and <kbd>e</kbd> is `é` as it should. Typing <kbd>altGr</kbd> and <kbd>S</kbd> gives me `Ş` as it should but typing <kbd>altGr</kbd> and <kbd>n</kbd> gives `~n` and not `ñ` as it should. It worked before and I can't find any setting and neither can I believe this is not a huge issue to others.

My keyboard layout is "German". `gnome-control-center -> Keyboard` has very limited settings. `Typing` (`Repeat Keys` and `Cursor Blinking`) and `Shortcuts`. There is nothing on `3rd level key` as suggested by terdon.

Comment: What is your keyboard layout set as? I get `ß` for AltGr+S but still get `ñ` for AltGr+n. Using US layout with dead keys. Also check your keyboard settings in Gnome, there are some relevant choices in the "Options" (such as which key chooses the 3rd level etc).

Comment: Can you please be more precise? In my task-bar I see "de" and clicking on it I can click on keyboard layout where it says "German". Switching to "es" I have the ñ where there is the ö printed on my German keyboard and yeah, this is actually one way to type this letter but it worked with dead key before. If I type AltGr+ I get ~ directly. It is not dead this key although `¸ and ´ are dead so I can type éè and Ş. As ¸ is reached through AltGr´ I'm especially confused about what's wrong. I can't find any "3rd level" settings.

Comment: If I go to settings->keyboard I see settings named "cursor blinking" and "repeat keys" but no "3rd level key".

Comment: Can't really be more specific cause I don't know. However, please [edit] your question to add your current keyboard layout. I take it you are using a german layout with dead keys? You should be able to find the 3rd level stuff in ControlCenter=>Keyboard=>options

Comment: In my Keyboard dialog, there is a **Layout Settings** link at the bottom left. Does your dialog have that?

Comment: @terdon in my GNOME keyboard settins there is no "options". Just delay and speed stuff. :( Ok, I found the shortcut to quickly switch between my languages, so with ñ being a key in spanish, I can live with this but I still have no idea how I broke this and how to fix it again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Gnome but I had a look at `gnome-control-center` and it looks like this is yet another useful function that the Gnome developers in their infinite wisdom decided to do away with.

It looks like you need to go to "Region and Language" => "Input Sources" and there, you add Spanish. Don't ask me why a keyboard layout (or a language) is considered an "Input Source". Anyway, once you've done so, you should be able to switch layouts with <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you but this is not what I want. I want to type ñ with my German keyboard typing ~ + n for those occasions that I need it but I don't want to get the rest of my layout be screwed up Spanish way. Not before my last German keyboard here in Chile dies.

Comment: As I said, I want to configure my keyboard such that typing ~ does not actually produce the tilde until I press it again and such that if I press n after it, I get an ñ. All this was the case half a year ago and all of a sudden this dead key behaviour disappeared. I still have dead keys like í, ì, ḿ etc. but not the ~.

Comment: AH! Sorry, I had not understood you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Compose Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key), configurable in many systems. The default key combination is <kbd>Compose</kbd><kbd>~</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>

Comment: I switched to a Spanish keyboard long ago but for the sake of evaluating your answer I searched my Compose key but couldn't find any setting or key that looks like a designated Compose key.